# Permission denied in android when create file

Tags: android

I want to choose image from sdcard and encrypt them. i have some problem with java io exception - permission denied. i declared use permission in android manifest READ and WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE but it doesn't work

[image]

then I open Device File Explorer and check permission, all of them don't have permission write

my code:

```
File file = new File(uri_result);//create path from uri
            final String[] split = file.getPath().split(":");//split the path.
            String filePath = split[2];

            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                File fos_enc = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/abcd.jpg");
                fos_enc.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fos_enc);

                byte[] k = "123456".getBytes();
                SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k,"DES");
                Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, enc);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    cos.write(buf,0,read);
                }
                fis.close();
                fos.flush();
                cos.close();
                showAlertDialog("Encrypt Successfully");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

permission denied because the sdcard don't access write the file and i have no idea to resolve this. Hepl me please :)
fos_enc=newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/abcd.jpg");

Comment: From API 23 and later you need to ask for permissions in `runtime` as well.

Comment: Please read [Request App Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add permission for it. Because you need external file read-write permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You need to request permission in runtime before doing that operation like below (this is needed for devices which use lollipop and above android os)

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @TrầnThanhBình nice to hear it. If it helps for u please upvote this as well. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Work with external storage requires to permission from user. You need to ask it from user in runtime. [Check this doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). Or access permission manually in settings of application for testing.

Answer (score 0):

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" fixed my problem